# Spring Jpa Specification, Many to Many, filter by lang and value

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, openjpa

I want to find only **by lang = "en"** and value like "pom" (pomme is the french translation for apple).

The fetched values will be :

```
FoodEntity : {
  names : [
    pomme, apple
  ]
}
```

Technically it shouldn't be retrieved because it's lang = "fr" .
It doesn't take in account the lang predicate. Does someone has any ideas?
It also retrieves all the names. I need only one!

In `@Query` everything works fine, but I need the Jpa Specification

```
@Query(value = "select f from FoodEntity f join fetch f.names fn 
where fn.value = ?1 and fn.lang = ?2")



@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "food")
public class FoodEntity {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "food_id_seq", sequenceName = "food_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "food_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "food_name_locale", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "food_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "locale_id")})
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<LocaleEntity> names = new HashSet<>();
}



public class LocaleEntity {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "locale_id_seq", sequenceName = "locale_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "locale_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "value", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String value;

@Column(name = "lang")
private String lang;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "names")
@JsonBackReference
private Set<FoodEntity> foods;

}
```

Inside the JPA Specification :

```
public class FoodSpecification implements Specification<FoodEntity> {

    private FoodCriteria searchCriteria;

    public FoodSpecification(FoodCriteria searchCriteria) {
        this.searchCriteria = searchCriteria;
    }


    @Override
    public Specification<FoodEntity> and(Specification<FoodEntity> other) {
        return Specification.super.and(other);
    }

    @Override
    public Specification<FoodEntity> or(Specification<FoodEntity> other) {
        return Specification.super.or(other);
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<FoodEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if(searchCriteria.getName() != null && !searchCriteria.getName().isEmpty()){
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.like(joinFoodName(root).get("value"), searchCriteria.getName() +"%"), criteriaBuilder.equal(joinFoodName(root).get("lang"), searchCriteria.getLang())));

        }
        return criteriaQuery.distinct(true).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})).getRestriction();
    }

    private SetJoin<FoodEntity, LocaleEntity> joinFoodName(Root<FoodEntity> root){
        return root.joinSet("names", JoinType.INNER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to retrieve by value and lang.

My mistake was to call twice times the method :

```
joinFoodName();
```

By doing this I created a secondary inner join totally independent.

About the fact of all LocaleEntities are fetched I didn't find any solution for the moment with JPA specification.